# Why does GHC do such lazy static analysis?

Tags: haskell

GHC will happily compile the following:

```
signum :: Float -> Int
signum x
 | x > 0 = 1
 | x == 0 = 0
```

without a peep about other unhandled cases, and leave them to be thrown runtime exceptions. TypeScript has better static analysis than this. What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: It doesn't do it *happily*. Set `-Wincomplete-patterns`/`-Wall`.

Comment: GHC does some reasonable static analysis on non-exhaustive pattern matching like the one above, but to benefit from that, one has to turn on warnings, or (IMO, even better) use `-Werror=incomplete-patterns`. Personally, I'm rather strict on non-exhaustive patterns, so I would have made that error to be the default, but it's not a deal breaker since we can turn it on.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the snippet you posted doesn't generate a decent warning is that GHC would have to special-case the `==` and `>` functions in order to do so. To GHC, these are just functions of the type `Float -> Float -> Bool`, with no information about their coverage of their domain. An exhaustivity checker that managed to catch the error in your code would have to be bolted on to GHC's already quite sophisticated exhaustivity checker, (which it would interact with in complex ways), just for these two functions.

In Haskell we tend not to write code like this, though. To accomplish the same task you should write the following:

```hs
signum :: Float -> Int
signum x = case compare x 0 of
  GT -> 1
  EQ -> 0
```

This reduces the number of comparisons you have to make, and it will indeed give a warning for your missing case (with `-Wall`). You need to add:

```hs
signum :: Float -> Int
signum x = case compare x 0 of
  GT -> 1
  EQ -> 0
  LT -> -1
```

This kind of exhaustivity checking is much more general and powerful than just catching some numeric comparisons, and if you know how to use it it can catch all the same errors.

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence: GHC does emit a warning with `-Wall`, since it considers guards to be potentially false (unless they are `True` or `otherwise`).